# Recuperar Valor Json

Tags: javascript, json, api-youtube

Estou incluindo em meu site meu canal do YouTube com os vídeos.
Mas tem uma parte do Json que não estou conseguindo recuperar.

Estou fazendo assim:

```
$.each($feed.items, function(i,item){
var url = item.videoId;
```

Comentei no código a linha para vocês verem do Json. Mas está vindo **undefined**.

```js
{
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"***/***"",
 "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 9,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"***/***"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "*************" ############################## AQUI
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2015-05-26T17:47:49.000Z",
    "channelId": "****",
    "title": "TITULO",
    "description": "",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "default.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "qdefault.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "hqdefault.jpg"
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "TESTE",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  },
```

Comment: Tente fazer assim: `var url = item.items.videoId;`.

Comment: Assim não tem como. Eu consegui solucionar. Eu dei um **console.log(item)** e vi como ele estava retornando. Vou postar.

Comment: Diego, se possível poste como resposta a solução e depois marque como aceita. =)

Comment: Só daqui dois dias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucionei a questão. Embora esse Json acima seja o retornado pela URL direto no navegador, abri meu *Inspect Element* e dei um `console.log(item)` dentro da função `Each()`.

Daí ele me mostrou:

```
Object = Item {
   id : {
      videoId: *****
   }
}
```

Daí eu fiz um `item.id.videoId` e funcionou legal.

Obrigado.